# Kotlin BufferedReader.readLine() cause infinite loop

Tags: java, kotlin, bufferedreader, infinite-loop, readline

I'm making simple Client - Server application in Kotlin. I came a cross a problem with BufferedReader.readLine(). My server sends few lines of text and after reading them BufferedReader blocks the program so it doesnt move on. Look like it still waits for input. I dont know how to fix it.
Here is my Client code:

```
package Client

import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.Socket

class ConnectionHandler(client : Socket) {
    private val reader : BufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()))
    private val writer : PrintWriter = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)
    private var running : Boolean = false

    fun handle() {
        running = true
        while (running) {
            read()
            write()
        }
    }

    private fun write(){
        var intput: String? = readLine()
        if (intput != null) {
            writer.println(intput)
            if(intput.toLowerCase() == "exit")
               running = false
        }
    }

    private fun read(){
        var output : String? = "Server:"

        while (output != null) {
            println(output)
            output = reader.readLine()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Server code:

```
package Server

import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.Socket


class ClientHandler(private val client : Socket) {
    private val reader : BufferedReader = client.getInputStream().bufferedReader()
    private val writer : PrintWriter = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)
    private var running : Boolean = false

    fun handle(){
        running = true
        writer.println("Welcome to Server")
        writer.println("Possible operations: + - / *")
        writer.println("Example input 1 + 2 (notice the spaces between signs)")
        writer.println("To Exit write EXIT")


        while (running){
            try {
                val text = reader.readLine()
                if (text.toLowerCase() == "exit"){
                    shutdown()
                    continue
                }
                val values = text.split(" ")
                val result = Calculator().calculate(values[0].toInt(), values[2].toInt(), values[1])
                writer.println(" = $result" )
            }catch (ex: Exception){
                writer.println("Something went wrong, need to exit")
                shutdown()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun shutdown(){
        running = false;
        writer.println("exit")
        client.close()
        println("${client.inetAddress.hostAddress} closed connection")
    }

}
```

The client reads last line "To Exit write EXIT" and then waits, dosent accept input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readLine()` will block and wait for input, and will return `null` only when the socket is closed. You need to adjust your client/server communication protocol so that a server sends a special marker when it's done writing, and the client exits the loop in the `read` function when it receives that marker.

Comment: Ok thanks and about this marker it can be like special sign or text for example if I add a line "EOF" when server is done writing would be OK?

Comment: It's your protocol, you can choose whatever you need. "EOF" looks good.

Comment: What about if message has no end charactrer and has no length control before how you can understand you read all message @yole